# How to remove "x" threshold on tabs in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

When you click the "x" to close a tab in firefox there is a threshold you must wait before clicking the next "x" of a new tab will close the window. This is annoying and I want to set this threshold to zero. Is there a setting in about:config?

Answer (score 2):

When I close a tab in FF 5.0.1 I can close the next tab immediately. I can close 4 tabs in a row (arbitrary number) with no hesitation at all.

Can you share what version of FF you are using? Is it possible that it may be related to computer performance, such as a slow processor? More information would be greatly helpful.

EDIT: One thing to try is to go to about:config and set 'browser.tabs.animate' to false. If that works, let us know. More info about this solution [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=10664135&sid=9613afe5836eb2bbb93a3bd4b1f6760f#p10664135).

Comment: I'm using Aurora (7 atm). But I know this happens to me on 5 and 6. Attempt to close one tab by pressing x, then immediately press x for the next tab; it wont close. This happens to me at work, school, and home all on different computers.

Comment: All of them are Aurora? Have you tried any of Aurora's support options? Being pre-beta, they might have more info over there. But check my EDIT above, we might have crossed our posts

Comment: Nope no difference